# Image source using project resource (WPF)

Tags: wpf, image, controls, my.resources

I added a bunch of images as project resources.
Now i want to use them in my WPF application using the image control.
How can I assign the resource to the source of the image control?

Answer (score 3):

First, mark you image file as a "Resource" in the properties window of Visual Studio.  Then you can quite easily reference the resource using the file name:

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="theimage.png" />
```

If you have put your image in a folder, you can use

```
<Image x:Name="image1" Source="/folder/theimage.png" />
```

Comment: Ok the image is a resource but when I try:
<Image Margin="5,5,195,35" Name="img1" Stretch="None" Source="img.jpg" />
I get the error:
Value does not fall within the expected range

Comment: Can you paste the entire exception message?

Answer (score 2):

You wanted to reference your image in XAML right?

like this

```
<Image Source="Resources\MyImage.png" />
```

and you dont need to add the image to the project resource. just add the images to your project via solution explorer