# get image from resource XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a WPF application, I should set button image depending on current culture. It works fine for strings:

```
<Label Content="{x:Static res:Resources.Buy}"></Label>
```

show string depending on culture, but with image:

```
<Image Source="{x:Static res:Resources.GetItFree}"></Image>
```

I get an error. Why and how to do correctly?

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386117/image-source-using-project-resource-wpf

Comment: it can't help me because this variant works without culture. My case depends on culture...

Answer (score 1):

I have done this before, but using a library: [Infralution.Localization.Wpf](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35159/WPF-Localization-Using-RESX-Files). It is very simple the way of doing the images resources references:

```
<Window Language="{UICulture}" x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
    ...
    Icon="{Resx ResxName=WpfApp.MainWindow, Key=Window.Icon}">...</Window>
```

This is the final image you get (it changes with culture):

[image]

Hope this reference could helps, it works for me...

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I already made localization for text and it works fine. Don't want to break working part :)